# Why does Proguard make APK files bigger even when minifier is enabled?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, proguard, minify

I'm new to Proguard configuration, so please correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

After playing with Gradle and Proguard configuration, I got two main options: either setting `useProguard false` or deleting that line.

First option:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Second option:

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

The thing is that in the first case my APK-file size is 8 mb but it is not obfuscated and in the second case it becomes obfuscated but gets more than twice the size: 18 mb.

Proguard rule is the same in both cases:

```
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
```

So how do I make my APK both small and obfuscated?

Comment: do you have instant run enabled?

Comment: No, I switched it off because of some building issues.

Comment: Ok, I had same issue because of instant run. it worked as expected for me after turning instant run off.

Comment: This may be because *Proguard* and *Android minifier* are completely different mechanisms. When you set `minifyEnabled` to true, but disable Proguard, you are using a minifier built into Android plugin. After enabling Proguard the built-in class minifier is disabled, and full-featured Proguard run takes it's place. Builtin minifier is younger and supports only subset of Proguard features while Proguard is more mature and sometimes may err on side of caution when deciding, which classes to keep. E.g., Proguard automatically keeps arguments of `Class.forName` if it can recognize them.